# Conversion of a CSV file to different form

Tags: python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

i have a CSV file with contents

> 01"815732013.0"1brand1"[100  76  64 ... 153 139  94]"
>
> 01"815732025.0"1female1"[183 192 201 ...  18  10   0]"
>
> 01"815732027.0"1male1"[204 214 221 ... 214 221 255]"

in one column

I need the contents in four columns like this,

```
col1    col2             col3       col4
01     "815732013.0"    1brand1     "[100  76  64 ... 153 139  94]"
01     "815732025.0"    1female1    "[183 192 201 ...  18  10   0]"
01     "815732027.0"    1male1      "[204 214 221 ... 214 221 255]"
```

How can i change this?
using python/excel/any other tools.

Comment: You've got to provide more than just one row. It's not clear whether or not you're separating these fields by the presence of quotation marks. Or by anything else present in the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to have to have the double quotes in the output file, then you should be fine with splitting the lines on the double quotes:

```
import csv
import io


text = '''01"815732013.0"1brand1"[100 76 64 ... 153 139 94]"
01"815732025.0"1female1"[183 192 201 ... 18 10 0]"
01"815732027.0"1male1"[204 214 221 ... 214 221 255]"'''


with io.StringIO(text) as f, open('output.csv', 'w') as of:
    writer = csv.writer(of, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for line in f:
        line = [r for r in line.strip().split('"') if r]
        writer.writerow(line)
```

This snippet of code is pretty straightforward. You're basically splitting on the double quotes and discarding empty strings.

If you wish your output file to contain the quotes, then you may have to use some regular expression to capture the fields:

```
import csv
import io
import re


text = '''01"815732013.0"1brand1"[100 76 64 ... 153 139 94]"
01"815732025.0"1female1"[183 192 201 ... 18 10 0]"
01"815732027.0"1male1"[204 214 221 ... 214 221 255]"'''


with io.StringIO(text) as f, open('output.csv', 'w') as of:
    pat = re.compile(r'(\d+)(\b".+"\b)(\w+)(\b".+"\b)')
    writer = csv.writer(of, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for line in f:
        line = pat.sub(r'\1;\2;\3;\4', line.strip()).split(';')
        writer.writerow(line)
```

This is very similar to the previous snippet, with the only difference being the regular expression. The expression groups the different fields according to your desired output. Those groups are used to generated a set of row values which are passed to the `writer.writerow` method to write the row in your destination file.

I hope this proves useful.